# How do i show my entire screen with a projector?

Tags: video, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

i have a problem making my entire screen shown, which is a problem when i want to show other people how to do anything in ubuntu.

i can choose between showing a part of my screen, or another part, but still not the entire screen.

menu - system - preferences - monitors

(i have nVIDEA graphics, with nVIDEA driver)

> It appears that your graphics driver
>   does not support the necessary
>   extensions to use this tool.  Do you
>   want to use your graphics driver
>   vendor's tool instead?

and i get the chance to say yes or no.

yes for nVIDEA driver configuration and no for Ubuntu's inbuilt (whatever it is) in which i can configure the size of whats shown on the projector.

how do i show my entire desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you get I guess that you have not yet installed the proprietary Nvidia divers. The open source driver is nouveau. After installing the vendor drivers you will have a Nvidia configuration tool in your System section that allows "cloning" of your display:

Open **nvidia-settings** and choose "XServer-Display-Configuration". Your projector should automatically be detected when choosing "Detect Displays". In the configuration part you should be able to choose "Clone Display".

Comment: You're welcome. I won't add shots then.